# A noun for a person who dominates as social conversation in a very loud voice

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What noun would one use for a person who dominates as social conversation in a very loud voice?
I have tried "monologist", but it doesn't sound appropriate. That sounds as though it refers to a profession.

Comment: There are terms for dominating conversation, and for speaking in a loud voice, but I'd be more surprised if there is one word implying both. Is one aspect of this more important than the other?

Comment: I might say _he's a loudmouth_, or _he's a talker_, with "talker" carrying a negative connotation.

Answer (score 2):

That's a ***conversational narcissist***:

> A ***conversational narcissist*** will do their best to limit the discussion to topics where they are knowledgeable and can ***take up the most airtime***.
>
> In addition to both ***dominating the topic*** and airtime of a conversation, a narcissist might come across as ***incredibly arrogant and superior***, making it even less likely that other people will cut in, for fear of being made to appear stupid, and thus enabling the narcissist to continue to ***monopolize everybody's time***. (*[Men's Health](https://www.menshealth.com/sex-women/a39145758/9-ways-to-tell-if-youre-gconversational-narcissism-doctor-ramani-durvasula-psychologist-explainsuilty-of-conversational-narcissism/)*)

It's a relatively new term (became common [after 1970's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conversational%20narcissism&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3))

Comment: Narcissisme is only a particular sort of psychological complex; loudness is not necessarily an indication of narcissism. The love of oneself does not come through in mere loudness. all loud conversationalists would be narcissists then.

Comment: The behaviour described in your answer could stem from a superiority complex, and have nothing or little to do with narcissism.

Comment: It's hard to get a word for someone who does two things, monopolizing conversation and speaking in a loud voice. This is a good answer for the first part, and I don't think you'll do much better.

Answer (score 0):

Without further characterization of such a person you could refer to them as a "*boisterous talker*".

> (SOED) **boisterous** **3** Of a person or action: rough or turbulent in behaviour or speech; (now *esp.*) exuberant, noisily cheerful

*Complement after some more thinking about this question*

Combining the answer of [user Aled Cymro](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/598850/349876) and the adjective shown above, a seeminly better term results.

- *A boisterous monologist*

> (SOED) **monologist** A person who talks in a monologue or solioloquizes. Also, a person who monopolizes conversation.

**Note**    I doubt there is a one-word term in which both ideas should be captured precisely enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Pontificator**, perhaps? From *pontificate*, which *Merriam-Webster* defines as

> to speak or express opinions in a pompous or dogmatic way

*He does not pontificate about whether one ought to choose, if forced to it, to betray one's country rather than one's friends …*

*Robin W. Winks*